# Python function to convert Binary digit to Hexadecimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I have another problem with a program that converts binary digits to hexadecimal. I have the program that runs well but displays the hexadecimal digit in small caps though the answer is required to be in caps as shown in the [question and sample run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5G7Y.png)

This is my code

```
def binaryToHex(binaryValue):
#convert binaryValue to decimal

decvalue = 0
for i in range(len(binaryValue)):
    digit = binaryValue.pop()
    if digit == '1':
        decvalue = decvalue + pow(2, i)

#convert decimal to hexadecimal
hexadecimal=hex(decvalue)
return hexadecimal
def main():
  binaryValue = list(input("Input a binary number: "))
  hexval=binaryToHex(binaryValue)

  hexa=h1.capitalize() #Tried to use capitalize() function but didn't worl
  print("The hex value is",hexa[ 2:4]) #strips off the first 2 digits
main()
```

[This is what is displayed when I run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFEoe.png)

Comment: Use `upper` instead of `capitalize`.

Comment: umm `hexa[ 2:4]` doesn't *just* strip off the first two digits... that'd be `[2:]`... also, I take it though this is an exercise of some sort and you're not allowed to just use: `format(int(binaryValue, 2), 'X')` ?

Comment: @JonClements I don't think there is any restriction for that. I can use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this comes up a fair bit - here's an answer that's fairly Pythonic and hopefully serves as a canonical reference for future questions.

First off, just keep the input as a string:

```
binary_value = input('Enter a binary number: ')
```

Then use the builtin `int` with a `base` argument of 2 (which indicates to interpret the string as binary digits) to get an integer from your string:

```
number = int(binary_value, 2)
# 10001111 -> 143
```

Then you can use an `f-string` to print your number with a format specifier `X` which means in "hex with upper case letters and no prefix":

```
print(f'The hex value is {number:X}')
```

Your entire code base would then be something like (sticking with two-functions and your naming conventions):

```
def binaryToHex(binaryValue):
    number = int(binaryValue, 2)
    return format(number, 'X')

def main():
    binaryValue = input('Enter a binary number: ')
    print('The hex value is', binaryToHex(binaryValue))

main()
```

Comment: I have changed my code to 

def binaryToHex(binaryValue):
 decvalue=int(binaryValue,2)
 hexadecimal=hex(decvalue)
 return hexadecimal
def main():
 binaryValue = input("Input a binary number: ")

 hexval=binaryToHex(binaryValue)
 
 hexa=hexval.upper() 
 print(f'The hex value is {hexval:X}') 
main()

Comment: I get an error that unknown format code 'X' for object of type 'str'

Comment: @PatienceMuthoki Yes... because you want don't want to do any other string conversations, you literally want to print the `int` you get with the format specifier X and it does all that for you. You literally only need the 3 lines above... you don't need to do anything else with `hex` or anything.

Comment: So 1) get the input, 2) convert it to an integer, 3) print that number with the format specifier

Answer (score 0):

One mistake you've made is h1 does not exist in the code and yet it's present.

.upper() on a string changes it to uppercase

```
def main():
    binaryValue = list(input("Input a binary number: "))
    hexval=binaryToHex(binaryValue)
    hexa=hexval.upper() 
    print("The hex value is",hexa[ 2:4]) #strips off the first 2 digits
```

output:

```
Input a binary number: 10001111
The hex value is 8F
```

Comment: Thanks it has worked on my local machine though the program used for marking indicates an error that what the standard output isn't what was expected

Comment: Could you post the error message. I am unable to understand the issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

just make one function...

```
def binaryToHex():
    binval = input('Input a binary number : ')
    num = int(binval, base=2)
    hexa = hex(num).upper().lstrip('0X')
    print(f'The hex value is {hexa}')
```

Comment: Have you tried this with an input of `00000000` - `.lstrip` doesn't do what you think it does here...

Comment: Sure i've tried what @Wira Bhakti has done and doesn't display the correct thing. Furthermore we are required to use 2 functions

Comment: @JonClements can you explain why 'X0X'.lsplit('X0') interpreted as a "" (blank string)...?

Comment: @Wira `.lstrip` removes all **characters** (not the entire string itself) in the string given from the start of the string until it encounters a character that's not in the characters given.... hence... `'ABCABCABC'.lstrip('BCA')` will give you an empty string, but `'ABCABCDABC'.lstrip('BCA')` will give you `'DABC'`...